# TIM router and USB device permissions (Samba)

Tags: router, usb, permissions, samba

I live in Italy and my internet service provider is TIM. I've got the "TIM HUB" as router, which is a branded product from Technicolor (product name: AGHP, software version: AGTHP_1.0.5). I've plugged an external hard drive to a USB port of the router. I suppose the resource is shared via Samba Filesharing (but I'm not an expert). Anyway, I can access the HD, I see the files, I can create, modify and delete many of them, but sometimes I can't delete the file and I get a permission error. If I look at permissions in Windows I see there are two users named "S-1-22-1-0" and "S-1-22-2-0" with full control, and my user doesn't have full control. I can't change this permission and if I try I get an error "failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied". What should I do?

Comment: Samba unmapped users are assigned a SID in the S-1-22-1 domain and 
unmapped groups are assigned a SID in the S-1-22-2 domain.

Comment: Thank you! You know how to map my user to Samba Filesharing in a router? I've read about doing this on Linux, but I don't know how to apply the steps described to a router...

Comment: Sorry, no idea :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explanation for these SIDs is found in the notes
[Samba 3 User and Group Changes](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/ChangeNotes.html#id2578661) :

> Unmapped users are now assigned a SID in the S-1-22-1 domain and unmapped groups are assigned a SID in the S-1-22-2 domain.

The problem you are experiencing is then explained:

> An example helps to illustrate the change:
>
> Assume that a group named developers exists with a UNIX GID of 782. In
>   this case this group does not exist in Samba's group mapping table. It
>   would be perfectly normal for this group to be appear in an ACL
>   editor. Prior to Samba-3.0.23, the group SID might appear as
>   `S-1-5-21-647511796-4126122067-3123570092-2565`.
>
> With the release of Samba-3.0.23, the group SID would be reported as
>   `S-1-22-2-782`. Any security descriptors associated with files stored on
>   a Windows NTFS disk partition will not allow access based on the group
>   permissions if the user was not a member of the
>   `S-1-5-21-647511796-4126122067-3123570092-2565` group. Because this
>   group SID is `S-1-22-2-782` and not reported in a user's token,
>   **Windows
>   would fail the authorization check even though both SIDs in some
>   respect refer to the same UNIX group**.

The solution that is proposed is as follows:

> The workaround for versions of Samba prior to 3.0.23, is to create a manual domain group mapping entry for the group developers to point at the `S-1-5-21-647511796-4126122067-3123570092-2565` SID.
>   **With the release of Samba-3.0.23 this workaround is no longer needed**.

Therefore, your choices as I see them are :

- Gain SSH access to the router and modify the Samba tables so as to give the
  SIDs from `S-1-22` the necessary "everyone" permissions.
  This will require good knowledge about the router's Linux and Samba versions,
  and a mistake is certainly possible.
- Get in touch with the Support of your internet service provider.
  They might be able to guide you in making these changes,
  or would have a firmware update for upgrading Samba to a version
  later than 3.0.23, where the problem is said to no longer exist.
  Samba version 4.x should be even better.

Comment: I don't know how to access the router... I've already contacted my service provider, but they can't solve the problem. They pretend is everything ok with the router and maybe the problem is with my PC. They asked if I want an inplace assistance (at payment, with a fixed 99€ call fee, and 50€ hour for a possible, but not granted, solution). I'm trying to find a different solution.
Now I'll see if an updated firmware is available.

Comment: There is always the third option of getting a replacement router, or of adding a hub behind the router, if there is no solution for the TIM router and Support is useless.