# What is Technicolor's AGHP

Tags: macos, router

I have a Technicolor modem/router. It has assigned a IP associated with AGHP.

Can any one tell me what the meaning of this acronym.

Should the modem be assigning this an IP as I use only static addresses.

Comment: It might be helpful to elaborate on where exactly you are encountering this acronym (what settings? etc.).

Comment: The Techicolor modem/router was supplied by Vodafone New Zealand with little documentation. When I installed the modem I ran a security sweep over my network and found a rouge IP, as all my IP are assigned static IP's. I assume that this IP is associated with the WAN setup. I get a description of the IP as "vodafone-dga0130vdf-nz-ap-acf25a.hub" associated with Technicolor AGHP. As at present I am on VDSL and awaiting Fibre. That all said if I block the IP it just reassigns itself to another address.

Answer (score 2):

#### Can any one tell me what the meaning of this acronym.

It is a product name associated with Technicolor Routers, in particular branded routers from the Italian ISP TIM ([Telecom Italia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecom_Italia)).

Most of the pages referring to this router are in Italian and I cannot find an expanded definition for AGHP. It may just be a product name with no further meaning.

Source [Modem TIM HUB Technicolor AGHP - We TIM](https://community.tim.it/t5/MODEM-ROUTER/Modem-TIM-HUB-Technicolor-AGHP/td-p/14052)

And:

> I live in Italy and my internet service provider is TIM. I've got the "TIM HUB" as router, which is a branded product from Technicolor (product name: AGHP, software version: AGTHP_1.0.5).

Source [TIM router and USB device permissions (Samba) - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1280435/tim-router-and-usb-device-permissions-samba/1283170)

Comment: Thanks David, that's the assumption I came to. Many thanks. Jose